# Burninate [effect]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request, meta-tags

There are 423 questions tagged [effect](/questions/tagged/effect). This seems to be a completely non-tag, that should be removed. It looks like it's being used for "How can I get this wavy effect?" type questions.

I think [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1815456) to the tag wiki sums up my argument best:

> Effect is a result or change of something. For example, a graphical
>   effect (adding sepia to pictures, page curling), sound effects (high
>   treble/bass, changing pitch), etc.

i.e. almost everything.

Comment: [Wiki Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1815456) status rejected now.

Comment: How about we just change it to [affect] and see if anyone notices?

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure about that @Lucifer. It was accurate as-is; it's just that the tag is too broad.

Comment: Yes, agree with you @benisuǝqbackwards

Comment: Agreed, and [the relevant questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[effect]+jQuery+UI) could be retagged `[jquery-ui-effects]`.

Comment: The potential effects of your suggestion are overly affecting @Lance :-). But, no, I doubt anyone would notice.

Comment: It's down to **398**!